# Adding a version number marker to logback log with minimal code changes

Tags: java, logback

I am attempting to add an application "version" number to the beginning of each log line. In my reading I noticed that "Markers" are what I appear to need.

In code I am using `@Slf4j` which is returning the `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` and throughout the code it is being used simply as `log.info("Hey Bob")`.  How would I go about pre-pending the Marker (`log.info(VERSION_MARKER, "Hey Bob")`) to every log statement without affecting the existing code?

I don't/can't go through thousands of lines of code and make the changes.

Or, is there a better way to do this?

```
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <append>true</append>
   <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n%wEx</Pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

So my assumption is to modify the Pattern above.

Comment: Global find/replace?

Comment: Personally, I'd adjust the pattern of the appender. Details will vary on how you are currently configuring your appenders, and where the version comes from.

Comment: Yeah, I figure the Pattern is what I'd need to change.  I guess my issue is how to incorporate this into the existing code base with minimal changes.  I'll add the encoder configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use system properties in your pattern, e.g. `%property{app_version}`

```xml
<Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %property{app_version} %m%n%wEx</Pattern>
```

When you run your app, add `-Dapp_version=1.2.3` to the command line.

You can also programmatically call `System.setProperty("app_version", "1.2.3")`, but depending when that's called, some things may have already been logged before that.

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#property

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  I was either going to use an Environment Variable or a Spring property.